# How to stop reallocation of an NSArray in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, arrays, nsmutablearray

I am using an `NSArray` and `alloc` it to in `viewDidload` method.

I have two views in my app and add data to this array from these views. The total number of rows shown in a table according to `[array count]`.

But the problem I'm facing is that when I call the view where I'm using this array from another view then this array realloc and due to this my array size again start from 0. I don't want that. I want the array size start from its last position.

So please help me to remove out this problem where I declare this array or any alternate to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the array lazily loaded.

Have the view where the array is located have a getter that looks like this:

```
-(NSArray *)theArray {
    if(theArray == nil) {
         theArray = [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease]; //If using ARC, don't autorelease
    }

    return theArray;
}
```

In your firstView's `viewDidLoad`, just call the array like this:

```
[self theArray];
```

Now in your second view, call the first array like this

```
[firstView theArray];
```